# Haskell GHC build error: Loading archives not supported

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I'm trying to link a foreign cpp library with haskell. Running `stack build` seems to build it correctly but when I try to run `stack repl` I get this error:

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 8.0.1 for x86_64-unknown-linux):
    Loading archives not supported
```

app.cabal

```
executable app-server
  ...
  include-dirs: /usr/local/include
  extra-libraries: symengine stdc++ gmpxx gmp
  ...
```

stack.yml

```
flags: {}
packages:
- '.'
extra-include-dirs:
- /usr/local/include
extra-lib-dirs:
- /usr/local/lib
extra-deps: []
extra-package-dbs: []
resolver: lts-7.1
```

I tried it on mac osx sierra and also debian jessie.
Using ghc-8.0.1 (from lts-7.1). 
I've installed `symengine stdc++ gmpxx gmp` on my machine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: [Relevant bug report on GHC Trac.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9438) The lack of diagnosis there makes me think it would be quite a lot of work to answer this question properly.

Comment: For some reason, the original question asker's answer was deleted, but it looks pretty on-topic and relevant to me. So I quote it here: "Turns out I didn't compile symengine as a shared library". It was marked as "not an answer", but that looks like an answer to me: if other people are getting this error, perhaps try building your foreign libraries as shared libraries and see if that helps the situation.